# How can I best compare the frequency of categorical values from two datasets with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to compare two sets of data, each with a long list of categorical variables using Pandas and Matplotlib. I want to get and somehow store the frequency of values for each variable using the value_counts() method for each data set so that I can later compare the two for statistically significant differences in those frequencies.

As of now I just have a function to display the values and counts for each column in a data frame as pie charts, given a list of columns (cat_columns) which is defined outside of the function:

```
def getCat(data):
    for column in cat_columns:
        
        plt.figure()
        df[column].value_counts().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.1f%%')
        plt.title(f"Distribution of {column} Patients in {dataname}")
        plt.ylabel('')
        
getCat(df)
```

Is it possible to append/store the returned values of value_counts() into a new DataFrame object corresponding to the each original data set so I can access and operate on those values later?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could first transform your value_counts Series into a DataFrame and then merge it with the original.

Below you have an example of how to do that.

```py
test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'eye_colour': ['blue', 'brown', 'brown', 'green'],
        'city': ['Paris', 'Paris', 'Lyon', 'Paris']
    }
)

cat_counts = test_df['eye_colour'].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
cat_counts.columns = ['eye_colour', 'eye_color_count']

display(cat_counts)

# beware that inplace changes your original dataframe while True
test_df.merge(how='left', on='eye_colour', right=cat_counts, inplace=True)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for your response! Would I make this iterable by assigning a placeholder dataframe and having the new counts from each column merged to it?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you mean. But you need to be ware that if you add any records to the dataframe, you need to update te eye_color_count column values. Could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to get the value counts for multiple columns in a large data set, and have the counts of each appended to/stored in a new data frame just for the values and their frequencies. So right now I am iterating over each column in the data set to get the value counts, but I want to actually store those value counts somewhere else.